# Why is part of my jinja working while the rest is just printed out as text?

Tags: html, go, jinja2, go-gin

I'm working on dynamically making a webpage with Jinja using Golang's gin library as the backend.
I have a function that returns me two maps which I iterate over to fill in the fields of my data-structure 'mike'

```
type mike struct {
    Name   string `form:"name"`
    Id     string `form:"id"`
    State  bool   `form:"state"`
}

func postForm(c *gin.Context) {
  name := c.PostForm("name")
  var alive, dead = Foo(name)
  if(!(len(alive) == 0 && len(dead) == 0)) {
    for nam3, id := range alive {
        var name mike
    name.Name  = nam3
    name.Id    = id
    name.State = true
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "thing.html", name)
    }
    for nam3, id := range dead {
    var name mike
    name.Name  = nam3
    name.Id    = id
    name.State = false
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "thing.html", name)
    }
    return
  }

}

func main() {
  r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
  r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "start.html", gin.H{
      "form": "name",
    })
  })
  r.POST("/", postForm)
}
```

I then pass in that data structure into the html file and use conditionals to see which block of to execute (green text if alive, and red if dead)

```
{% extends "layout.tmpl" %}

{% block body %}
  {% if {{.State}} %}
        <form action="/display" method="post">
        <ul style="color:green;">
          <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="name" value={{.Name}}>
          {{.Name}} is {{.State}}
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </ul>
        <form>
  {% else %}
        <form action="/display" method="post">
        <ul style="color:red;">
          <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="name" value={{.Name}}>
          {{.Name}} is {{.State}}
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </ul>
        <form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

All the Jinja syntax is printed but the ones enclosed in {{}} actually get converted to a value and I end up getting something like this where only part of the Jinja works

[Partially working Jinja](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Myk.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening because I'm completely stumped. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Go's template engine has nothing to do with Jinja. See https://pkg.go.dev/html/template and https://pkg.go.dev/text/template.